# Function to select table rows based on certain conditions

Tags: postgresql

```
create table my_table(x int, y int);

create function get_rows() 
    returns table (lie my_table) as $$
begin
    -- 1 First try
    --select * from my_table where x < 0;
    -- 2 If empty then try 
    --select * from my_table where y < 0;
end; $$
language plpgsql;
```

How to implement a function that selects rows based on condition 1, but if such rows don't exists then select based on condition 2. If nether conditions can be satisfied then return an empty table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can us "IF EXISTS" to test the first condition. Then depending on the result use RETURN Query for the appropriate select;

```
create or replace function get_rows() 
    returns table (lie my_table) 
    language plpgsql
as $$
begin
    -- 1 First try
    if exists (select null from my_table where x < 0)
    then 
       return query 
          select * from my_table 
           where x < 0;
    -- 2 If empty then try            
    else 
       return query
          select * from my_table 
           where y < 0;
    end if;                  
end; $$;
```